# ASP.NET windows authentication box when webservice called

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, authentication

Got a very strange issue, never seen it before. Basically in the admin section of our website, a user attempts to edit something by clicking a button.

This button attempts to call a webservice (via jquery, which the page will then use to show an edit form in shadowbox).

However the user informs me that instead of the form popping up as usual it is blank for a few seconds. Then this pops up:

[image]

Any ideas? The webservice is in the admin section, which requires the user to be in a role (which the user is, otherwise they would never get to the point of being able to click the edit button).

Answer (score 1):

This is normal if your web service is located on a different machine as your web server.

If the two machines are on the same domain, then the browser will attempt to use the default network credentials that has been cached.

This dialog will also pop up if the default credentials used to access the web server (which could be anonymous) does not have access to the resource (folder) where the web service is running.  The pop up gives the user an opportunity to enter another set of credentials.

Comment: web service is a simple asmx webservice so it is on the same web server.

Comment: Why is the browser doing this?? Authentication (logging into our website) is handled by the ASP.NET application. When a request is made for this webservice the cookie which contains the authentication info is also sent along with the request, so the application should know whether so and so has permissions to a webservice. No???

Comment: Eg: Your web page is at Inetpub\wwwroot\F1.  Your web service is at Inetpub\wwwroot\F2.  The web app at F1 is configured for anonymous authentication.  The web service at F2 is configured for Windows Authentication.  When you call the web service, the application pool identitiy will be used.  If F2 file access permissions is not given to the app pool identity, you will get this challenge.  This is an example, just an example. There are many other possible scenarios.  If you can provide more details on your situation, perhaps it will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi. Thanks that makes perfect sense. Except in this case! The website is set up for forms authentication, and the webservice is a part of the website (just in the admin section, which requires the user to be in the "admin" role).

Comment: Can you check the file permissions of the the web service folder, to make sure that all rights are inherited from the parent folder.